# Why are my twitter chrome (desktop) browser notifications disabled?

Tags: google-chrome, twitter

i have the latest Chrome vrsn + the notification settings here are enabled for https://Twitter.com:443

chrome://settings/content/notifications?search=notification

screenshot: https://www.evernote.com/l/AIFnyO1e3AxIgr-Lm4sdwDdoo3pCb3Kcif0B/image.png

Answer (score -1):

Could you check in security parametters, the lock left in your address bar, if notifications are not disable for twitter specifically.